# Why success_message (MessageMixin) is called after form_valid ? shouldn't it be called after save() method

Tags: python, django

I am writing a generic CreateView in Django and using this example from documentation.

```
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from myapp.models import Author
class AuthorCreate(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Author
    success_url = '/success/'
    success_message = "%(name)s was created successfully"
```

This works fine if the field in success message (name) is unprocessed and saved as is from form i.e.
If I try to output something like

```
success_message = "%(id)s was created successfully"
```

where I process save id in custom save method I call on the Model,
it throws a key error. 
Isn't this bad? Shouldn't the success message be created after a successful save rather than `form_valid`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The success message's `form_valid` method is called **after** the instance has been saved. However, the success message is constructed using the form's `cleaned_data`, not the model instance. This allows the mixin to be used with all forms, not just model forms.

The Django docs for [adding messages in Class Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-messages-in-class-based-views) explain what to do -- override `get_success_message` instead of setting the `success_message` attribute.

```
class AuthorCreate(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
        return "%(id)s was created successfully" % {'id': self.object.id}
```